# Related data into ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've created a ViewModel, to get related data from 3 models:

```
public class GezinUitleen
{
    public Speelgoed Speelgoed { get; set; }
    public List<Uitleen> Uitleningen { get; set; }
    public List<Gezin> Gezin { get; set; }

}
```

the classes involved:

```
 public class Speelgoed
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string omschrijving { get; set; }
    public int? batterijId { get; set; }      
}

public class Gezin
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    }

public class Uitleen
{
    public int UitleenId { get; set; }
    public int speelgoedId { get; set; }
    public int lenerid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("fkspeelgoed")]
    public Speelgoed speelgoed { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var gezin = _context.tblGezin
            .Where(m => m.Id == id).ToList();

        var viewModel = new GezinUitleen()

        {
            Gezin=gezin,
            Uitleningen = _context.TblUitleen
                .Where(uit => uit.lenerid == id).ToList(),
            Speelgoed= ???????????? this is where I am stuck....
        };
        return View("Details", viewModel);
    }
```

I want to display the 'omschrijving' property of the Speelgoed class.
How do I get that into my ViewModel ??

Comment: What do you want to do? What is the resource of speelgoed ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 _context.TblUitleen.Include(uit=>uit.speelgoed).Where(uit => uit.lenderId == id).ToList()
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be:

```
 Speelgoed= context.TblUitleen
                        .FirstorDefault(t => uit.Id== id).omschrijving
```